# on click java script redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to redirect the cube image to another link after clicking the cube image
now in js it redirects to google.com but it opens in another window
but i wanted it to display in the same window

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="span10">
                    <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
                        **<div onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');" data-caption="Fans" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/inventory.png"></div>**
                        <div data-caption="Paul Scholes" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/search.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Wayne Rooney" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/yourFile.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Sir Alex Ferguson" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/shareFiles.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Champ" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/custFile.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Group" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/custQuote.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Ryan Giggs" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/saleOrders.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="David Beckham" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/custInvoice.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Champ" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/vendorProfile.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Group" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/vendorQuote.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Ryan Giggs" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/buyOrders.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="David Beckham" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/vendorInvoice.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Champ" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/accountsReceivable.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Group" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/customerRMA.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="Ryan Giggs" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/production.png"></div>
                        <div data-caption="David Beckham" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/CRM.png"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `_blank` to `_self`. This will make the target change from being a new window to the current window

jQuery:

In general I avoid attaching events to a div, and use links or buttons to use click events, but anyway...

```
$('.melonhtml5_gallery').find('div').click(function(){
  window.open($(this).attr('data-image'), '_self')
  //you can refer to attributes using the following:
  //$(this).attr('data-caption')
})
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but its not working in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7pHMy/3/

Comment: and is it possible to achieve the same functionality in jquery

Comment: @user1943618 jsfiddle can perform oddly in certain situations e.g. `alert` - have you tried testing it outside of a fiddle?

Comment: To answer your jquery question, yes it is. I'll update my answer

Comment: @AbePetrillo: thanks for your reply but i wanted each div to point to different links.... how to achieve it

Comment: @user1943618 I thought there was enough there to figure it out, but anyway, I've changed the code so it will go to the url specified in data-image.